# Why is my for loop only returning the first element?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm new to Google Scripts & writing one to export data from Google Sheets to Slack. I set up the Slack export code successfully, but no matter what I try my formula only grabs the first element.

```
function reporting() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('REPORTING')
    var startRow = 1; // First row of data to process
    var numRows = 52; // Number of rows to process
    // Fetch the range of cells A1:B52
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 1);
    // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
    var data = dataRange.getValues();
    var i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < numRows; j++) {
            return data[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why it won't return the entire array?

Comment: That's because when you return something, the function does not continue to run. So this function just returns the value at i = 0, j = 0 and halts

Comment: What are you trying to **do** with the elements of the `data` array? Send them one-by-one? Send them row-by-row? Sum them together? Wrap them in HTML for special formatting?

Comment: @tehhowch I want to print them one-by-one.

Comment: Print them *how*? Are you trying to send a slack message for every cell? That's 52 rows and (due to your script's for loop logic error) 52 columns of messages with contents from just one cell (2704 messages). That's absolutely going to trip an API rate limit somewhere, and rightfully so.

Comment: @tehhowch yes, I noticed that error and updated to 1 column and got it down to 35 rows. I would like the formula to send each of these to slack. do you know the correct way to write a script for this?

Comment: Write an export method that works with the array of values.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you've got the return statement within your inner for loop block.
You shouldn't return, as this would just grab your first element and then exit the function.
It should be as the following:

```
function reporting() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('REPORTING')
  var startRow = 1; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 52; // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A1:B52
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 1);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < numRows; j++) {
        // do something with data[i][j], call a write/export function
    }
   }
   //return statement should be here.
   return <result>;
}
```

Comment: thank you Yahia! do you know a good resource for creating a write/export function?